# Nginx configuration for multiple domain names with same root folder

Tags: nginx

I have configured nginx server request process on AWS as below:
The below code fragments are form custom conf file inside nginx

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  abc.tk www.abc.tk;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #}



    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Initially,  I had one domain(as above), It is working fine, But now I want to do the same redirection for another domain to the same root folder. By the way, I have not mentioned root folder here, it is coming from nginx.conf. I tried different approaches from reading the online sources but didn't get any success.
Below is what I am trying right now but it is not working. Giving me 521: web server down error. Also, I have used cloudflare for ssl for both the domain.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  abc.com www.abc.com abc.tk www.abc.tk;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #}



    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Quick help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to redirect the user to a specific domain or simply serving the page for all the domains listed in server_name?

Comment: yes...the latter one i would want, to serve the page for all domains listed in server_name

Comment: I also tried regex in server name like abc.* www.abc.* but the same result

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this way:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  abc.com www.abc.com abc.tk www.abc.tk;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/;
        }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try it out, buddy

Comment: yes....still that error. I have several location blocks in my conf file.I added yours and removed my one. It broke my existing working scenario. I have two angular projects in two folders. with different server context , i am running those

Comment: have you tried running "/usr/nginx/sbin/nginx -t"  to see if it gives you some error? If the server is down, probably there is some error in some conf file

Comment: Adding up new domain name in server_name would not  work?

Comment: Yes, it should! I suspect there is a problem with the SSL certificates

Comment: I also tried the previous working domain name replacement with the new one. It doesn't work that either but when I switch it back to old one, it works. Old domain name works in any case but not the new one. Do we configure the domain name somewhere in nginx? I have forgotten whether i did or the old one or not